# Is it possible to convert only audio in video file using avconv?

Tags: avconv, avi, ac3

I have downloaded a video file in AVI format and it seems to have A52 (AC3) encoded audio. VLC for iOS can't play this audio format.

Can I convert audio of this video file to AAC or something more standard across Linux and iOS? How should I go about this?

- Extract audio from video. Convert audio to standard format. Merge it back.

OR

- Can avconv directly convert audio without me needing to extract it first?

Answer (score 3):

After playing with `avconv` myself, I found a possible solution.

`avconv -i inputfile.avi -strict experimental -c:a aac -c:v copy outputfile.mp4`

However I tested the file and it worked on iOS 8.1, I have not played it in full to be sure. I will update later.